# how to reuse single activity infinite times?

Tags: java, android

My app has an album style feature that users can pick/take photos from device and load it in every page in this album.

Now the number of this album pages is up to user and should be unlimited. On the Other hand the codes that is being used in activities as you could imagine are exactly same. I have wrote code once and I just want to reuse this activity for each page of album. how should I achieve this?

Since there are thousands of apps that are provide this kind of functions I know there is a good way but i'm unable to find that. Just a trick or a link to a tutorial or even a small explanation is good enough.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you need each page to be an Activity? I think it would be easier to create an Activity once and just change the contents based on the page #.

Comment: if the user can add -as many as wants- then it SHOULD be 1 activity, and you pass a param like albumId or other info to load related photos into the view

Comment: @TassosBassoukos My question is exactly how to achieve your way. my problem is in this "change the contents based on the page" thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `next()` method, and change every layout view in the page with this function, so that you are in same activity but only views are being changed.

Comment: Most likely only the data is changing not the views or layout.

Comment: I meant that by changing views. In the same layout, a text in a TextView or an image in an ImageView will change. So, data will change.

Comment: That's what I do in my apps, in the same activity I just change the information.

Comment: can you explain more what should happen in this next() method? sorry I'm rookie.

Comment: I need more specific parts of your code for that. Basically you'll just use setText(), setImageResource() methods etc..

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add the data to be displayed to the "extras" of the Intent which you use to start the activity.

Alternatively, you might want to look at using a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`. You might also want to look at using `ViewPager` to be able to swipe through the fragments which display the album data.

Comment: can you explain the difference between Fragment or Activity and why using that can be more helpful. sorry, But I'm a little new to android.

Comment: @SaDeGH_F I suggest you do a little research first. There is already a lot of information out there about Fragments.